# UIAutomationElement Focus Leave: seemingly no current implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have been working with a GitHub-offered package UIAComWrapper for about 4 months now.

I have come to learn a lot about it, and its limitations.

I have also learned that I need to be resourceful on my own, because there is very little documentation and/or forums that discuss issues on this package.

The class within the package I have used the most is AutomationElement.  (Please do not confuse this with Microsoft's version.)  Think of these as actionable text boxes in a browser, like search fields, or form textboxes (name, address, etc)

AutomationElement is provided an event handler for when one of its objects receives focus.  That tests nicely.  However, nowhere in this package can I find a reliable way to handle when the same AutomationElement loses focus.

I won't be able to submit code examples.  This question is an SOS to those who have had the (mis)fortune of working with UIAComWrapper.

Comment: Strange the `FocusChangedEventHandler` should fire for both `Focus` and `UnFocus`, where and when are you registering/dergistering the event?

Comment: As part of my Window Constructor -> Initializer set of methods.
I believe I have been able to detect the Focus Leave from that same event...however - I don't believe there is a way to discern between FocusEnter vs. FocusLeave when that event fires.  None of the EventArgs indicate any difference.

Comment: Now...do I need to implement the " -= " (minus-equal) deregister?  I attempted to implement that action, but it only rendered that AutomationElement inactive.

Comment: Well not sure if you need to in your case, I have a good feeling we use this in a WAY different manner to most people, my only advice would be to trawl the sourcecode, that's what we have to do :)

Comment: Been that.  Done there.  
I've been out to sea trawling on several fruitless voyages.
This issue has been tabled for weeks.  I only thought to reach out now.  Surely someone out there has had some similar experience.
At the very least, I'd be interested to see if anyone else is suffering at the hands of UIAComWrapper.